# How do you convert a cell to number

Tags: excel

I copied over the text from a web based report in to excel. The text from the web based report is formatted to number but it will not read as a number.

Also tried to "text to columns" to convert it to number will not read as a number.  I need to put in a simple sum function but it will not sum, returns as #VALUE!

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. `SUM` used on text doesn't return an error (maybe you're just using `+`). Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Sorry a multiplication formula is what is triggering #VALUE!  The sum function is just not reading the text from the report and only returning one value.

Comment: First step would be to try both `TRIM` and `CLEAN` and then coerce to a number using `--`.

Comment: If you have something like “=left(A1)” and the result should be a number then “=left(A1)*1” can work.

Comment: This worked Solar Mike - thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

IN a new column or row, try using VALUE() in conjunction with TRIM() to remove extra spaces, and CLEAN() to remove non-printing characters, e.g. a line break. You may or may not need to use TRIM() and CLEAN().

```
=VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN(A1)))
```

Then use your SUM formula on the values in the new column or row.

VALUE function - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2

TRIM function - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/trim-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9

CLEAN function - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clean-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41